# matlab, string array and load as title head

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am using matlab and trying to make an string array consist of serious of numbers and - sign.
    These are my cvs file titles ( I have 30 of them but I just show 4 of them here).Later on I would
    like to  load the file one by one using a for loop.  So far I tried many things, did not work. It
    treats as character not string. I tried to read as a character but there was issues regarding the
    array as well.  Does anyone knows how to make a string array out of this and load the files one
    by one and  solve this.

```
Thank you

Here are my cvs title files

2010-11-03-2010-11-04;   
2010-11-12-2010-11-15
.
.

my code
========
TimeTitleList=['2010-11-03-2010-11-04';  '2010-11-12-2010-11-15';  
'2010-11-15-2010-11-18';'2010-12-03-2010-12-06'; ....] 


for i=1:30

TimeTitle=TimeTitleList(i,1);    
filename = (['data/',TimeTitle,'.csv'])
...

end
```

Birsen

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `.csv`... You can use [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to get a list of files and [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) to read them in.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you save each string in a `cell` array.  By placing this into a normal matrix, you are effectively creating a 2D array of characters, and the way you're accessing the strings will not give you what you originally intended.  Actually, you would only be accessing one character instead of the entire file name.

As such, try something like this:

```
TimeTitleList = {'2010-11-03-2010-11-04'; '2010-11-12-2010-11-15'; ...
                '2010-11-15-2010-11-18';'2010-12-03-2010-12-06'};
```

The `{}` denotes the creation of a cell array.  Once you do this, you would thus access each string using curly braces instead of round braces.  Therefore, your `for` loop would look like this:

```
for i=1:30

    TimeTitle=TimeTitleList{i};   %// Note curly braces! 
    filename = (['data/',TimeTitle,'.csv'])
    ...

end
```

Answer (score -1):

try concatenating the series of numbers with "strcat"

```
a=strcat('2010-11-03-2010-11-04')
b=strcat('2010-11-03-3460-11-04')
```

Then, save them in TimeTitleList, and it should work...

:)

Comment: Doing `strcat` on a single string doesn't make sense.  `strcat` is meant to concatenate multiple strings together, but you are only providing a single argument.  You are effectively doing, for example, `a = '2010-11-03-2010-11-04';`.  Did you mean to concatenate both `a` and `b` together as a string?

Comment: What I did is check it on MatLab, when doing what he does you get an array of n:20. And when trying to do the openning of the file you can't make it.But in the other hand, if you do what i do, you get an array of n:1, and you are able to open the file. Just try it. It worked for me time ago. Not the fastest way but works. :)